# How to preload video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have an mp4 video that my page visitor can view by clicking the link:

```
<a href="videos/myvideo.mp4" target=_blank">Introduction to My Product(16:02)</a>
```

No video tags, etc.  I just depend on the visitor's machine having something to play an mp4 video with. (Seems like a good bet.)

Now I'd like to preload the video as soon as the visitor lands on the page. I know images can be preloaded with something like;

```
<img src="images/img1.png" class="hiddenPic">
```

where "hiddenPic" is `display:none`.  Is there something simple like this you can do for videos, to make the video load but never play? The idea, of course, is to make the video start immediately when the link is clicked.

The page is HTML5.

Thanks

Comment: if the page is HTML5 why wouldnt you use the `<video>` tag? that has an easy to use `preload` attribute

Comment: You should use an HTML5 `video` tag and use the parameter `preload="auto"`

Comment: My understanding of HTML5 video is that this puts the burden of playing the video on the browser and the browsers don't all agree on what the video format should be.  They won't all play mp4, for example, so you have to generate three versions of your video: OGG, mp4, and WebM.  I was trying to avoid that.